# Help! Used Wrong Great Stuff

Tags: subfloor

I was building a subfloor in my basement.  3/4" osb on top of 1" xps, and spray foam around the perimeter.  I was in looking at Great Stuff foams saw Floor and Wall saw it was good for subfloors and foam panels so I grabbed it and went on my way.  Only until AFTER I applied it to the entire perimeter did I see ADHESIVE!  Will this still serve the purpose?  Or am I going to need to cut it out and apply the proper foam insulation?

Insult to injury I also got it on my hand :(

Answer (score 1):

As long as it dries & fills, good enough. If it doesn't do those things then just door & window foam over it or minimal expanding. No biggy. Mineral Spirits will help to get it off the skin, applied & scrubbed several times, but it may still have to wear-off some.

Comment: So you think it will provide an air tight and water resistant seal?  I was purposely putting extra in allowing it to flow over because I wanted to make sure it was fully covered and I would go over later and cut it flush before laying the osb.  My other concerns are it may shrink a little over time or not provide enough insulation that it may allow condensation on the concrete.

Comment: I'm picturing this is the pink spray stuff, it may not be. But yeah, I wouldn't suspect any performance difference, especially if it needs to be cut off. The air-pockets are what matters, not the components. And, air-tight is no issue, that's got that licked. It wouldn't be an adhesive if it shrunk, so it may be a good mistake after all.